# How to copy/run my .app file from the builds folder of xcode to the /Applications folder on my iphone? (jailbroken)

Tags: iphone, root, jailbreak

so I've developed an app. Now I manually placed the .app file into the **/Applications** folder of my iphone (root). Than I did:

> It sounds like the application isn't
>   signed. Download ldid from Cydia and
>   then use it like so: ldid -S
>   /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph
>
> Also be sure that the binary is marked
>   as executable: chmod +x
>   /Applications/AccelerometerGraph.app/AccelerometerGraph

([via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-real-iphone-device))

Than I used UICache to make the app visible. And if I run it it shows a black screen for a 1/4 second and then it closes...(I'm not a member of the iphone dev program).

Did I something wrong?

Is there a better way?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Not sure but maybe that App is simply crashing? Check the console.

Comment: Hm..If I installed it normaly with xcode on my ipod touch it runs fine but I can't execute any commands because the app is in a "sandbox". The App just displays a label. That's it. Mayby you could make a sample project (with xcode ;) but xcode 3 would be also enough) and test it?

Answer (score 5):

I just spent a perfect Saturday afternoon looking for a solution to the exact same problem. It is a code signing problem.

Here is what I was using **Xcode4** and **iOS 4.3 SDK** . I was building to a test device an iphone 3G running iOS 3.1.2 (jailbroken)

**NOTE**: ldid method did not work for me and kept on throwing the following error ([Some Details on why its not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288894/building-for-jailbroken-devices-on-ios-sdk-4-2) I tried using armv6 architecture through xcode4 but ldid still gave the same error):

`codesign_allocate: object: MyAppName.app/MyAppName malformed object (unknown load command 4)
util/ldid.cpp(582): _assert(0:WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)`

**Here is what worked for me:**

**Step 1. Create a Self Signed Certificate**.

> 1- Launch Keychain Access.app. With no items selected, from the Keychain menu select Certificate Assistant, then Create a Certificate.
>
> Name: iPhone Developer
>   Certificate Type: Code Signing
>   Let me override defaults: Yes
>
> 2- Click Continue
>
> Validity: 3650 days
>
> 3- Click Continue
>
> 4- Blank out the Email address field.
>
> 5- Click Continue until complete.
>
> You should see "This root certificate is not trusted". This is expected.

[via](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464/iphone-app-minus-app-store/37522) (note: you dont need to be a member of the iphone dev program to make this work even though the title of the accepted answer in the link might suggest that)

**Step 2. Set xCode to allow the self-signed certificate to be used**

> You have to edit the **Info.plist** file under /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist
>
> (I have installed xcode at a different location so that path for me was xcode4/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Info.plist)
>
> 1- You will not be able to edit the file in its current location so just copy it to the desktop and open it in a text editor.
>
> 2- You need to Replace all instance of **XCiPhoneOSCodeSignContext** with **XCCodeSignContext** and save the file.
>
> 3- Then drag and drop the edited file back to iPhoneOS.platform folder and replace the old file. (Make sure xcode is not running if it is then restart it)

**Step 3. Change the Code Signing Identity setting in your project**

> Change the code signing identity for your project and your target to **iPhone Developer**
>
> 1- In xcode4 you have to select your project (from the left navigator panel) -> Select you Project from the center under (PROJECTS) -> Build Settings -> Code Signing (expand the menu) and change all options to **iPhone Developer**
>
> 2- In xcode4 with your project selected from the left panel in the center of the screen you will see PROJECT and TARGETS. Now select the targets and do that same: Targets -> Build Settings -> Code Signing (expand the menu) and change all options to **iPhone Developer**

**Step 4. Build the App and Deploy**

> 1- Make Sure at the top of xcode next to the run and stop buttons under Scheme you have **iOS Device (your device name) selected and NOT Simulator** (this is how its done in xcode4)
>
> 2- Open the Scheme menu and with the iOS Device Scheme selected click edit scheme. Select Run from the left menu and under the Info tab **set Build Configuration to Release**
>
> 3- Now make sure you have your iOS device connected and its scheme is selected and hit Run (note: you will get some warnings but as along as the build succeeds you are okay)
>
> if all goes well you should be able to see YourApp.app under the Products folder on the left side now select YourApp.app open it in Finder. Your app should be in a folder called **Release-iphoneos** Copy it to **/Applications** dir on your iOS device and respring or UICache to make it appear.  (note: you dont need to use ldid now)

Hopefully your app will launch fine. I have only tried this with xcode4 so not sure if it will work for older versions.

Comment: so does that mean I can submit this binary to the Cydia store?

Comment: I managed to host the apps I made on my own Cydia repository and I can install and update them through the Cydia app on my phone. I haven't tried any on the Cydia store so not sure.